# Laravel application architecture issue. Model being called between Controller & View?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, file-get-contents

I'm having an issue that seems to imply I'm not understanding how architecture in Laravel works correctly. I'm new to Laravel, but I thought I knew this. When the client requests a page, a Controller is called, which pulls data from the Model and passes it to the view. If the preceding statement is correct, then why is this problem occurring:

In my `JourneyController`:

```
public function journey($id) {

    // Find the journey and the images that are part of the journey from the db
    $journey = Journey::find($id);
    $imagesInJourney = Journey::find($id)->images->keyBy('id');

    // Perform some manipulation on the article. THE ERROR OCCURS HERE. 
    $journey->article = str_replace('[[ ' . $image . ' ]]', $html, $journey->article);

    return View::make('journey', array(
        'journey' => $journey,
        'title' => $journey->name,
        'bodyClass' => 'article'
    ));
}
```

This controller is called, and pulls data from my `Journey` model (below). In particular, I have an attribute, which I called `article`, that I am manipulating prior to sending to my controller:

```
class Journey extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'journeys';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;

    // Database relationship
    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC METHOD
    public function getArticleAttribute($value) {
        return file_get_contents($value);
    }

}
```

As you can see, I'm editing the `article` field, which was merely a link to a file, and replacing it with the actual file contents using PHP's `file_get_contents()` function. So my understanding is that when this gets returned to the Controller above, `$journey->article` will contain *the article itself*, not the *URL to it*.

Yet, for some reason, this statement in my controller, where I replace portions of the article text with images, is causing issues:

```
 $journey->article = str_replace('[[ ' . $image . ' ]]', $html, $journey->article);
```

In my view over at `journey.blade.php`, I attempt to output `$journey->article`, expecting it to be the article text with the images added in, yet I receive the error:

```
ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) file_get_contents(*entire article content here*): failed to open stream:     Invalid argument (View: app/views/journey.blade.php)
```

Why does this happen when I attempt to call `str_replace()`? If I comment it out it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your getArticleAttribute method gets called every time you get/echo this attribute when you get for the first time there is no problem (this is where str_replace function executes) but when you try to get article attribute again ( this is where you echo in view page) you already changed the value of attribute so your function tries to execute file_get_contents again.

The solution would be having a flag in journey class and setting it to true while file_get_contents executed, and returning the attribute itself for other calls.

Like;

```
class Journey extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'journeys';
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    private $article_updated = false;

    // Database relationship
    public function images() {
        return $this->hasMany('Image');
    }

    // THIS IS THE PROBLEMATIC METHOD
    public function getArticleAttribute($value) {
        if($this->article_updated){
            return $value;
        }
        else {
            $this->article_updated = true;
            return file_get_contents($value);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: This seems diametrically opposite to what MVC is supposed to do. Is there any documentation regarding this "feature"?

Comment: Actually this is about OOP, the ORM uses magic __get function for the model properties, and when you define an accessor it calls your accessor function (https://github.com/illuminate/database/blob/master/Eloquent/Model.php#L2551)

In your case, you have journey model with a article property, (all your properties as defined in "protected" attributes array) and every time you write `$journey->article` ORM's __get function gets called, and so it your get accessor. You can check "encapsulation" for this.